# Why does dash.js fail to play this MPEG-DASH stream in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, html5-video

This MPEG-DASH stream

```
http://54.241.9.147/new-fandor/vod/21/2157/dark_star_FILM_v11.smil/manifest_mpm4sav_mvlist.mpd
```

doesn't play in dash.js -- it plays the first segment at the lowest bitrate, switches to the next higher bitrate and stops after loading the second bitrate's init information. You can see this by pointing Chrome at [the dash.js reference player](http://dashif.org/reference/players/javascript/1.0.0/index.html), entering the stream URL in the top box and hitting Load. Open the JavaScript console to see that dash.js reported a media error, which means that the video element had a .error.

The same player is able to play this stream in IE11 without error.

These streams, each of which contains only one of the bitrates that play in the above sequence, both play without error in Chrome, so it's not that the underlying media is just somehow corrupt.

```
http://54.241.9.147/new-fandor/vod/21/2157/dark_star_FILM_v11_0.smil/manifest_mpm4sav_mvlist.mpd 
http://54.241.9.147/new-fandor/vod/21/2157/dark_star_FILM_v11_1.smil/manifest_mpm4sav_mvlist.mpd
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Chromium person says that this is due to audio sample rate switching, which Chrome doesn't support yet: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=315330 Although each of our videos' video bitrates should have had the same audio bitrate, some videos had different audio bitrates for different video bitrates. The solution was to reencode those videos correctly.